Как запустить .py из .sh? (Двойным щелчком)
Описание проблемы:
У меня OS: линукс Mint/Open Suse Leap 16. + Idle3 среда для разработки python3 + мой код питон с библиотекой pygame.
Задача запустить .py из .sh двойным щелчком по файлу в одно действие ).

Это все-таки сайт вопросов и ответов. Можно отвечать на свой вопрос самому, но тогда ответ должен быть отдельным постом (кнопка "отправить ответ" внизу). А из вопроса эту часть удалите.

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/178576

A) Зайдите в Настройки/Приложения/Настройте ассоциацию файлов для sh (я её случайно сбил её... ):
Для sh-файла: Выбирайте: /usr/bin/bash.
B) Чтобы, запустить 0.py из 0.sh:

Создаем в 0.py:
print("Hello World")


Создаем текстовый файл 0.sh:
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo 1111  
python3 0.py 


Переходим в папку проекта с 0.py и 0.sh файлами.
открываем консоль:
$ chmod +x 'Перетаскиваем файл и заключаем его в такие кавычки'
нажимаем (enter)
/.'Перетаскиваем файл и заключаем его в такие кавычки'
нажимаем (enter)



(Важно: Попутно смотрим: не выдает ли ошибки, чтобы не было лишних пробелов и символов в конце строк,- если они есть, - удаляем backspace'ом.)

После этого все работает!


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
